# Is it possible to style the Facebook Like button shown faces to be inline

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I'd like to show faces (`data-show-faces="true"`) on my FB like button, but I'm using it in a panel that is very wide but where I can't afford to use a lot of vertical space.  I would like to display the faces in the same row as the button, not in a new line.

Is there a way of either configuring the control to do this, or a safe way to do it in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no good way to do this. Facebook controls the iframe that gets rendered when you use `fb:like` and they don't make the users who like that object available to you for privacy reasons (those faces are personalized for the user who's viewing them).